# What is causing my Intel AX200 wifi adapter to be undetected on Debian 11 with firmware-iwlwifi?

Tags: debian, iwlwifi

I recently installed Debian 11 (bullseye) onto a second SSD in my computer (so I'm dual-booting with Windows on another). I used the official installation image and had to include the [firmware-iwlwifi package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-iwlwifi) on the installation drive which worked fine and was able to use my wifi adapter during installation.

Since then, when I boot into Debian and check the GNOME settings dialog I see "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". However, this is inconsistent and it's sometimes working fine (I've yet to notice any pattern behind this).

I've discovered that my wifi adapter is an "Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz" and you can see in the snippet of output from `lspci -v` here it is listed along with the iwlwifi firmware:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I can also see that the module is currently loaded, as per this snippet of output from `lsmod` (note that third column is showing it is used by 0 running programs):

```
iwlwifi            294912  0
```

I've done some searching around and all previous questions I could find related to this (such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed)) are for an older Linux kernel or older versions of Debian (suggesting to use the backported package). However, as I understand it, my adapter should be supported by the latest version of package-iwlwifi for bullseye which I have installed.

What might cause this behaviour or what steps might I take to find and resolve the problem?

Comment: WiFi has nothing whatsoever to do with Bluetooth. `iwlwifi` is the drivers for Intel WiFi interfaces, most often built into laptops with Intel CPUs. What exactly is "is sometimes not found"? Is the card not detected/configured, doesn't connect to the network, ...?

Comment: @vonbrand I only mention bluetooth because the adapter also supports bluetooth and that portion seems to be working when the wifi isn't.

And to clarify, it seems as though the card is not detected.

Comment: My Intel combined wireless/bluetooth adapter does bluetooth on USB; maybe yours does to? That would explain bluetooth working. To debug: check vendor and device ids (`lspci`, `lsusb`), check which kernel modules are loaded (`dmesg` after boot, `lsmod`), check if the vendor/device id is in the kernel module which should pick it up (`modinfo`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the problem thanks to these specific lines of output from `dmesg | grep iwl` which show iwlwifi failing to probe the adapter:

```
[   56.478063] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   56.511447] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Searching more specifically for failed probing lead me to find that the problem was due to duel booting with Windows 10 and having the Windows "fast startup" feature enabled (on by default). Disabling this has resolved the issue for me.

Relevant text from
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled:

> If you have a dual-boot machine with a recent version of Windows and start seeing problems during initialization of the WiFi device when booting Linux, the problem could be due to the “fast startup” feature on Windows.
>
> With this feature enabled, Windows don't really shut down the entire system, but leaves things partially running so you can start the machine faster again. Try to disable this option, on Windows 10 it should be in “Control Panel→Hardware and Sound→Power Options→System Settings”. Select “Chooose what the power buttons do” to access the System Settings from the Power Options. Then disable the “Fast Startup” option in “Shutdown Settings”. This will cause Windows to fully shutdown and may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you install both Windows and Linux, disable fast startup in Windows (in Control Panel’s power settings), then restart, enter Linux, solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am dual booting and have fast boot disabled in Windows.  It didn't resolve the problem.  It appears this is a regression issue with the firmware.

sudo dmesg | grep firmware

You will see at the bottom if your version failed to load.

sudo YourFileManager or use sudo mv in terminal to do the following.

Go into /lib/firmware and find the .ucode version that failed when you looked at dmesg | grep firmware and rename it with extension.Disabled or wipe it out.

Example: iwlwifi-cc-a0-63.ucode.Disabled
(If you are having issues with Broadcomm or something else your dmesg | grep firmware will show a different firmware file)

After disabling/wiping the bad firmware then:

sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
reboot

The highest version in /lib/firmware will load.

Mine works with 5.302607] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 62.49eeb572.0 cc-a0-62.ucode op_mode iwlmvm

Version 63 doesn't work for me.  Legion 5 AMD, Intel AX200 wifi

I will submit a bug report.  Happy surfing.