# Intel wireless interface not showing up debian 11

Tags: debian, intel, iwlwifi

I have a Galaxy Book Pro 360 with the onboard intel wifi 6e ax210 chip.

I installed a fresh dualboot net-install of debian via ethernet.

Now i want to use it with wifi but no success...

Here are some informations about my system:

lspci -kv:

```
...
2d:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0024
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 82300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

it doesn't show up in `rfkill list`

`iw list` is empty

`ip a` returns:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enx4865ee1805b1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
...
```

```
root@debian:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enx4865ee1805b1  no wireless extensions.
```

`modprobe iwlwifi` returns also nothing

and last but not least `dmesg | grep iwl` spits out these errors:

```
root@debian:~# dmesg | grep iwl
[   54.589514] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode
[   54.589519] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   54.589527] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[   54.589754] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   54.589760] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[   54.598220] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[   54.775103] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
[   54.775122] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x324cd670
[   55.025425] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[   55.025435] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[   55.025443] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 0
[   55.037571] iwlwifi 0000:2d:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Also disabling fast startup in windows 11 dual boot didn't change anything:
[Windows Dual Boot wifi problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667809)

Comment: Welcome, what is your kernel version?

Comment: Thanks, it's the newest debian 11.

```Linux debian 5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux```

Comment: Check if this [AskUbuntu post helps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326386/ubuntu-20-04-lts-driver-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax210-160mhz).

Comment: Upgrading the kernel?

Comment: I already have 5.10+ kernel and that was the fix for that post..?

Comment: I forgot, did you install the non free firmware? By default the Debian images don't have these.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update/1360291#1360291

Thank you so much, the comment under this solution you sent me, directeted me to this solution a simple one liner and a reboot and bam it's working!

Comment: Great! kudos :D

Answer (score 2):

[Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update/1360291#1360291)

this simple one liner and a reboot fixxed my issues!

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing the latest Linux kernel from Debian backports should resolve the problem.

Add Debian backports to `sources.list` as described in the [docs](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/):

```
sudo echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free' >>/etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```

Install the required firmware:

```
sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Install the latest Linux kernel for your architecture. For example, for amd64:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-amd64/bullseye-backports
```

Comment: I didn't need to install the linux image with `/bullseye-backports`, updated kernels showed in my bash autocomplete after updating. Went from 5.10 to 5.19. Thanks

Comment: @NuclearPeon `linux-image-amd64/bullseye-backports` depends on the latest kernel in Backports, such that it is installed automatically.